# Is it worth to install some Debian UEFI 64bit on Intel Atom

Tags: debian, uefi, 64bit

I am using for some time some Ubuntu clones, because they works on my uncommon computer setup (Intel Atom, UEFI, 64Bit). Unfortunately because of this specific architecture, I can not drop on this machine every Linux type as I want.

But I worked a very long time ago in Debian, and I was very happy because of him minimalism etc.
I read some articles about Debian + UEFI, but I read there that it is quite difficult operation or that it is immposible.\

Do you have simmilar opinion as this two upside, or maybe have some tricks and tips how to install this OS in right and easy way.

Comment: 64-bit UEFI is by far the most common architecture on new PCs today. In fact, in 2017 Intel announced that they will remove legacy BIOS support from UEFI this year (2020).

Comment: If the system has limited memory (say 2GB), then using 32 bits OS might spare some RAM and despite the slower instruction set, might be overally faster.

Comment: @A.B not neccessarily; in fact, Linus has stated long ago that systems with more than _one_ gigabyte of RAM are better off using 64-bit addressing: https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/

Comment: @MichaelShigorin   I'm often using a 64 bits laptop with only 4Gb but I keep using a 32 bits Firefox. Swapping is worse than any 64 bits speed up. 32 bits uses less memory that's all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that your system combines a 64-bit Atom CPU with a 32-bit UEFI; this was common for Atom systems in the past. This causes problems for a number of distributions, and Ubuntu has had specific support for this scenario for a long time. Debian 7 couldn’t be installed in 64-bit mode on these systems, which is why there are many claims online that it doesn’t work; however, [mixed mode is supported since Debian 8](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Support_for_mixed-mode_systems:_64-bit_system_with_32-bit_UEFI), so it should be possible to install current releases of Debian without issue.

Download a [multi-arch Debian 10 installation image](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst), choose the 64-bit installation option, and the installer will set up 64-bit Debian with a 32-bit loader.

Comment: I think you have completely right. Before I read your comment, I decided to try install Debian 9 x64 on this machine. In fact, the notebook wokrs perfectly, but have to solve issue with missing sound. I have idea how to fix it, because during installation I got message with informations which files are missing. Now I am gonna try to import it in good place. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Another potential trouble manifesting as freezes during GPU operations: http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051 (the infamous `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` hardware bug).